# Find each position of same characters in a string through SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my data set

```
Year        Month       Holiday list
----------------------------------------------------------
2007        1           WWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWH
2008        4           HWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWW
```

I want to write SQL query to get below output wherein the position of each "H" is displayed.

```
Year        Month       Holiday list
-----------------------------------------------------
2007        1           3 4 10 11 18 19 25 26 31
2008        4           1 7 8 14 15 21 22 28 29
```

The `INSTR` function in Oracle returns the position of first character. So, I cannot use it.

I could write a Function and pass the Holiday List column value to it. Loop through the string and
find the position of each "H". But, I want to achieve this through plain SQL select query.

How to find each position of same characters in a string through SQL query in Oracle database?

Comment: I don't think the base Oracle string functions, or even regex functions, can do this.  I would guess that you would need a UDF for this, where you can iterate over every character in the holiday list string.  A database isn't the best tool for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might do it. You can use the `INSTR`function and a hierarchical query to go through the string and then use the `LISTAGG` analytic function to concatenate the results.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 2007 year, 1 month, 'WWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWH' holiday_list FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2008 year, 4 month, 'HWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWWWWWHHWW' holiday_list FROM DUAL)
SELECT year, month, (SELECT LISTAGG(INSTR(holiday_list,'H',1,LEVEL),' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < INSTR(holiday_list,'H',1,LEVEL)) S
FROM data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get a list, see the dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0ec33ff5f2217a16eec625a65c06958f)

```
SELECT id, INSTR(some, 'H', 1, c.no) AS Pos
FROM tst CROSS JOIN consecutive c
WHERE INSTR(some, 'H', 1, c.no) > 0
```

This gives you a list of the days with an H. You could then try to transpose this list. But be warned, there is an intentional CROSS JOIN there, so for every row in your data you will get up to 31 rows with this statement. Like Tim Biegeleisen said, it may be better to use an UDF for this.